# Is there any Flickr Image search API for ActionScript\MXML developers?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, api, search, flickr

Is there any Flickr Image search API for ActionScript\MXML developers? (if special keys are not needed for using it will be big +)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/as3flickrlib/

This is a library written by Adobe. You need the AS3 Core Library to use this (also by Adobe): http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any library that allows you to access the API without a key. It's easy to get one from Flickr though:

http://www.flickr.com/services/apps/create/apply

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing supported by Flickr, but there are some projects that the [Flickr API page](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/#kits) links to that expose their API.